# Flutter launch map link

Tags: flutter, google-maps

Estoy desarrollando una app y tengo las coordenadas de los objetivos que necesito.
La aplicación muestra en el listado los sitios y cuando usuario hace tap, necesito que el sistema le muestre con que aplicación necesita abrir esa ubicación y que muestre la ruta para ir. Por ejm. Google Maps, Waze, etc.

Estoy trabajando con [url Launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) y no consigo hacer un solo link para que me abra cualquier mapa.
Ahora tengo que hacer un link para abrir google maps y otro para abrir con cualquier otra app (waze en este caso).

Link WAZE

```
void launchWaze(double lat, double lng) async {
  Uri geoUrl = Uri.parse('geo:${lat.toString()},${lng.toString()}');
  launchUrl(geoUrl);
}
```

Link Google Maps

```
void launchGoogleMaps(double lat, double lng) async {
  Uri url =
      Uri.parse('google.navigation:q=${lat.toString()},${lng.toString()}');
  Uri fallbackUrl = Uri.parse('https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=${lat.toString()},${lng.toString()}');

  try {
    bool launched = await launchUrl(url);
    if (!launched) {
      await launchUrl(fallbackUrl);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    await launchUrl(fallbackUrl);
  }
}
```

Si abro link con función google maps me muestra esto.

[image: Aqui tengo que elegir gmaps, si elijó waze, abre la app pero no toma coords]

Ahora, si abro con función Waze me muestra distinto, pero elijo google maps y no me muestra el marcador.

[image: Aqui Waze y Mapinr si abre las coors adecuadamente, pero gmaps no]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu pregunta me ayudo mucho con un error que tenia, ahora te comento que el marcador de maps no aparece porque le hace falta algunos parámetros, sustituye los métodos por unos solo así como lo hice yo y funciona al cien con las apps que ocupen localización para darte una dirección

```
static Future<void> openMap(double lat, double lng) async {
  Uri url =
      Uri.parse('geo:${lat},${lng}?q=${lat},${lng}');
  launchUrl(url);
}
```

Espero que te haya servido.

Edito:

Este código sirve para mandar a la PlayStore o AppStore, si es que Maps no esta instalado

```
import 'package:external_app_launcher/external_app_launcher.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class MapUtils {
  MapUtils._();

  static Future<void> openMap(double lat, double lng) async {

      Uri url = Uri.parse('geo:${lat},${lng}?q=${lat},${lng}');

    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    if (await canLaunch(url.toString())) {
      // ignore: deprecated_member_use
      await launch(url.toString());
    } else {
      await LaunchApp.openApp(
        androidPackageName: 'com.google.android.gms.maps',
        iosUrlScheme: 'maps://',
        openStore: true,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad @Miguel Zurita,  ya no sabia que hacer. 
Si me funcionó, 
cambié un poco el código porque salia deprecated.
Soy nuevo en flutter, no se si esta bien, 

 Uri url = Uri.parse('geo:$lat,$lng?q=$lat,$lng');
      try {
        await launchUrl(url);
      } catch(e){
        await LaunchApp.openApp(
          androidPackageName: 'com.google.android.gms.maps',
          iosUrlScheme: 'maps://',
          openStore: true,
        );
      }

Comment: No se como marcar pregunta como resuelta, saludos

Comment: Actualizo: tuve que quitar paquete external_url_launcher porque usa inyecta QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES y Google dese el 20 de julio Restringe el uso de este permiso, a no se de qué justifiques a plenitud. En mi caso tuve que quitar este paquete porque yo podía justificar